# How to show some stuff or a message beetween the main content in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I have a rails app where users can Sign Up/Sign In and post stories, follow other authors, what i want to achieve is how to put some content like "Authors to follow" in between of the main content while the user is scrolling (Like what twitter does with "Who to follow".

with react i have created a `User_Follow_suggestion_container`:

```
<%= react_component('FollowSuggestionsContainer') %>
```

It works fine, now i want to know, where to place it, so it can  come randomly or after scrolling down to 20 or 30 posts.

[image: Same like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your react component is inside a loop, you'd do something like this:

```
<%- @tweets.each_with_index do |tweet, index| %>

  <%= tweet %>

  <%- if index == 20 ( or 30 or even rand(20..30)) %>

    <%= react_component('FollowSuggestionsContainer') %>
```

Sorry if the syntax is wrong. I haven't used ERB in years..

Edit: If you want it after scroll, you'd probably do something with JavaScript instead of Ruby/Rails.